# Redistributing files in a folder

Tags: bash

I need to do some job with my files and the steps are as follow:

1. Delete from the selection all folders where there is a mention of test in json.json file
2. Delete folders without wav files

I have written the below script and don't understand why it doesn't `echo` for empty directory?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for obj in rom/*; do

        if [ -d "$obj" ]; then

              if 
                 grep -w test $obj/*.json; then
                 echo $PWD/$obj
                 rm -rf $PWD/$obj
              fi

              if
                  find $obj -type f -name "*.wav"; then
                  echo "ok"
               else
                  echo "In this dir you haven't .wav files"
#                 rm -rf $PWD/$obj
              fi
        fi

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I written like this

```
#!/bin/bash

for obj in folder/*; do

        if [ -d "$obj" ]; then

              if 
                 grep -w test $obj/*.json &>/dev/null; then
                 rm -rf $PWD/$obj
              fi
        fi
done

for obj in folder/*; do

         if [ -d "$obj" ]; then
             if 
                 ls $obj/*.wav &>/dev/null; then
                   echo "" &>/dev/null
                 else
                   rm -rf $obj
             fi
         fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in [man find](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> EXIT STATUS
>        find exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur.  This is deliberately a very broad description, but if the return value is non-zero, you should  not
>        rely on the correctness of the results of find.

So even if `find` doesn't find the files you were looking for, it will return true because it processed all files successfully.

You could use command substitution like this:

```
if test "$(find $obj -type f -name "*.wav")"; then
```

to check if the directory contains any `.wav` file.

**Suggestion:** please consider quoting `$obj` like this `"$obj"`. You could face problems with directories or files with spaces in their names.

Comment: THX your answer.